# How can I properly install pyEPR to my environment using Anaconda?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

What I'm currently doing to install pyEPR to my environment is:

1. conda activate bash1pilot
2. pip install pyEPR (Which works)

The problem is present while in a Jupyter Notebook: when I have any code relating to pyEPR, such as `from pyEPR import ProjectInfo`, I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyEPR'

[see full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmJRo.jpg)

I'm open to feedback and suggestions on how to get this working.  Thank you.

Comment: Make sure when you start notebook you are using correct environment

Comment: I installed pyEPR in the environment I'm working in already. When I try repeating the command it says "requirement already satisfied"

Answer (score 1):

When you activate the environment, did you also install and register and ipykernel for that environment? My guess is that your virtual environment *bash1pilot* isn't registered with Jupyter as a kernel. For example:

```
conda activate bash1pilot
pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --name bash1pilot
```

Now when you open Jupyter, you should be able to go to Kernel->Change Kernel and have *bash1pilot* show up in the list. Select that and now your module should be found. Note: You must restart any open Jupyter instance for the kernel change to take effect.

Comment: Despite following these exact steps and verifying ipykernel is installed within my environment the module not found error in jupyter notebook persists.

Comment: Sorry for any previous confusion I thought the problem was fixed but the kernel never actually was able to start which is why I didn't see any errors and mistaken it for working when I tested it on the bash1pilot kernel. A kernel called Python 3 is the one which the errors show up.

Comment: Since bash1pilot is not showing up in your kernel list, then it is definitely not registered. `python -m ipykernel install --name bash1pilot should register it with Jupyter and exiting and restarting Jupyter should fix that. If not, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. In jupyter notebook it is showing up in my kernel list. The problem is in Anaconda it says I successfully installed pyEPR but on jupyter notebook it's as if I never installed it. (The first time I installed anaconda I was able to get it to work but I had to uninstall and reinstall to fix something I messed up doing something else.)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem I was facing by downgrading to python 3.10 and following the regular steps of installing pyEPR through the terminal in a new environment. Thank you everyone for your suggestions and inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `pip` is, that it sometimes can't resolve all the correct dependencies. Pip doesn't do a good job of resolving transient dependencies, sometimes is does very bad actually. So, there might be some dependencies that pip is missing out, hence the `import error`.

First, check if you're running your Jupyter-Notebook with the correct `conda-environment`. If you are then, you can install `pyEPR` in your conda environment with the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyepr-quantum
```

Installing with conda worked perfectly for me. My python version is `3.10.12 64bit`.

```
import pyEPR
from pyEPR import ProjectInfo
print(pyEPR.__version__)
print(ProjectInfo.__class__)
```

Output:

```
0.9.0
<class 'type'>
```

Follow the official guide for more: **[pyPER documentation](https://pyepr-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)**

Comment: When I did "conda install -c conda-forge pyepr-quantum" within my environment that worked however when I closed and reopened Anaconda to activate my environment and open jupyter notebook I kept getting the same issue in my code as if something in the jupyter notebook code was not connecting to Anaconda.

Comment: you are supposed to activate the conda environment first, then run jupyter notebook on it. Not the other way around

Comment: I did that sorry for the confusion. I have two kernals, one named after my environment and one named python 3 (ipykernel). I'm fine with any one of them working but preferably I want the pyEPR working on the python 3 kernel. Sorry for any previous confusion I thought the problem was fixed but the kernel never actually was able to start which is why I didn't see any errors and mistaken it for working when I tested it on the bash1pilot kernel.